# NOAUTH Authentication required. Redis settings on docker compose for django

Tags: django, docker, redis, docker-compose, celery

I keep on getting the error message: **redis.exceptions.ResponseError: NOAUTH Authentication required..** (I'm using celery to perform background tasks).

My settings.py looks like this:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://user:my_strong_password@'+REDIS_IP+':6379/0'
```

the docker-compose I have:

```
services:

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: jh_redis
    ports:
     - '6379:6379'
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes --requirepass my_strong_password
```

you can see that my attempt to provide the password (--requirepass) is exactly as it shown in the settings.py however, while the docker is up and running I still get the subject error message.

I have tried different combination such as:

--requirepass user:my_strong_password

but still didn't work.
Note: when I take off the entire command line - it works (but 32 hours after - I get the error message and it stop working).

What should be the appropriate settings in docker-compose to have it work smoothly?

Comment: Your Redis server is exposed to the public network and is being connected to by someone who sets a password on the instance at least, if not something worse. Secure your Redis with a password at the very least, if not disconnect it from the world, to reduce the threat.

Comment: @ItamarHaber thanks. Could you share how you secure it on docker? I'm still straggling with the syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the celery docs, your broker url should be in this format:

```
redis://:password@hostname:port/db_number
```

i.e., you should remove `user` from the broker_url.

Comment: I haven't forgotten your answer! For some reason it takes few days to see if it works not (on the server side). I just revised it based on your strategy and let's see if it can last more then 4 days. Position and hold. Thanks again